# Can't show gist code in Drupal blog

Tags: nodes

I'm completely new to Drupal. I've installed [Gist Input Filter](https://drupal.org/project/gist_filter). In blog, when I write `[gist:6351376]`, as said in the project page, it just shows as it is. Please help.

Comment: You must also configure it to apply to format that you are using for blog posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Home > Administration > Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats*. Click *Configure* next to text format you are using for blog posts, probably Filtered HTML. On the *Enabled filters* list, check Gist. On the *Filter processing order*, drag it to the end, or at least to be after *Convert URLs into links* and *Limit allowed HTML tags* filters.